# Ruby (with Rails) convert a string of time into seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date, time

So, I've got a string of time... something along the lines of

```
'4 hours'
'48 hours'
'3 days'
'15 minutes'
```

I would like to convert those all into seconds.  For `'4 hours'`, this works fine

```
Time.parse('4 hours').to_i - Time.parse('0 hours').to_i
=> 14400 # 4 hours in seconds, yay
```

However, this doesn't work for 48 hours (outside of range error).  It also does not work for 3 days (no information error), etc.

Is there a simple way to convert these strings into seconds?

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking Ruby to do with Time.parse is determine a time of day. That's not what you are wanting. All of the libraries I can think of are similar in this aspect: they are interested in absolute times, not lengths of time.

To convert your strings into time formats that we can work with, I recommend using Chronic (`gem install chronic`). To convert to seconds, we can do everything relative to the current time, then subtract that time to get the absolute number of seconds, as desired.

```
def seconds_in(time)
    now = Time.now
    Chronic.parse("#{time} from now", :now => now) - now
end

seconds_in '48 hours'   # => 172,800.0
seconds_in '15 minutes' # => 900.0
seconds_in 'a lifetime' # NoMethodError, not 42 ;)
```

A couple quick notes:

- The `from now` is is why Chronic is needed — it handles natural language input.
- We're specifying `now` to be safe from a case where Time.now changes from the time that Chronic does it's magic and the time we subtract it from the result. It might not occur ever, but better safe than sorry here I think.

Comment: I'd go with Chronic for this too.

Comment: Chronic will work, but Chronic Duration may make life easier.  Have https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration . A nice blog article about date/time parsing - http://everydayrails.com/2010/08/11/ruby-date-time-parsing-chronic.html

Comment: @Gokul Looks helpful. The API is kind of garish, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
4.hours => 14400 seconds
4.hours.to_i 14400
4.hours - 0.hours => 14400 seconds 

def string_to_seconds string
  string.split(' ')[0].to_i.send(string.split(' ')[1]).to_i
end
```

This helper method will only work if the time is in the format of number[space]hour(s)/minute(s)/second(s)

Comment: You're starting with a Fixnum, but I think he's starting from strings input from the user.

Comment: Yeah in all honesty I just noticed that and was skimming earlier. Having said that, it seems to me if the time strings will always be in the described consistent format then why not parse the string and use rails datetime helpers.

Answer (score 4):

```
'48 hours'.match(/^(\d+) (minutes|hours|days)$/) ? $1.to_i.send($2) : 'Unknown'
 => 172800 seconds
```

Comment: This will fail on: 'a day', 'one day', '1 week', '1 month', '48 Hours', etc. This is a step up from `def solve_complex_problem; return 'answer'; end`.

Comment: Yes, passes the examples in the question though. I don't understand the second sentence.

Comment: Ever take a programming course where the book told you that you needed to write an application that responded a certain way? The point is, rather than writing it to literally respond to the examples, you should infer what *function* it should be performing and write it as such.

Comment: That makes more sense. Would you add those features in your first comment even if you knew they aren't going to be used? Assuming that the question is about user input is guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Chronic will work, but Chronic Duration is a better fit.
It can parse a string and give you seconds.

```rb
require "chronic_duration"
ChronicDuration::parse('15 minutes')
# or 
ChronicDuration::parse('4 hours')
```

http://everydayrails.com/2010/08/11/ruby-date-time-parsing-chronic.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you would get some good work out of [chronic](http://www.rubyinside.com/chronic-natural-date-parsing-for-ruby-229.html) gem.

Also, here is some [good to know info about dates/times in ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/3-new-date-and-time-libraries-for-rubyists-3238.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
>> strings = ['4 hours', '48 hours', '3 days', '15 minutes', '2 months', '5 years', '2 decades']
=> ["4 hours", "48 hours", "3 days", "15 minutes", "2 months", "5 years", "2 decades"]
>> ints = strings.collect{|s| eval "#{s.gsub(/\s+/,".")}.to_i" rescue "Error"}
=> [14400, 172800, 259200, 900, 5184000, 157788000, "Error"]
```

Comment: This is tricky, but very dangerous to use `eval` with user input. If you used a regexp to validate that the input was only what you expected (e.g. `/\d+\s+(?:minutes|hours|days|...)/`) then this wouldn't be too bad. Perhaps better to parse it out and use `.to_i.send(duration_string)`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, it is vulnerable to injection attack, it would be better to regex check it beforehand.