# How to convert raw string of time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails (>= 6), what would be a good way to convert raw strings representing time to an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object ? For instance, something like:

```
45 min
1 h
```

I read some answers in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623869/ruby-with-rails-convert-a-string-of-time-into-seconds), but the issue is that the [chronic](https://rubygems.org/gems/chronic/versions/0.10.2?locale=fr) gem is not maintained anymore.

Comment: If you can make sure that your strings follow a certain format, there are some answers in the discussion that don't rely on the gem. Like this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624060/9595653
or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624079/9595653. In your case you would need to trnaslate the abbreviations for the time into the rails methods. `h` -> `.hours` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module DurationParser
  class ParseError < StandardError; end
  # This is an example of how to extend it with aliases
  ALAISES = {
    hours: [:h, :hr],
    minutes: [:m, :min],
    seconds: [:s, :sec]
  }
  EXP = /^(?<value>[\d*|\.]*)\s*(?<token>\w*)?$/.freeze

  # Parses a human readable string into a duration
  # @example
  #   DurationParser.parse('2 hours, 1 minute')
  # @return [ActiveSupport::Duration]
  def self.parse(string)
    string.split(/and|,/).map(&:strip).map do |pair|
      matches = pair.match(EXP)
      method = token_to_method(matches[:token])
      raise ParseError unless method
      (matches[:value].to_i).send(method)
    end.reduce(&:+)
  end

  private
  def self.token_to_method(token)
    ActiveSupport::Duration::PARTS.find do |p|
      p == token.downcase.pluralize.to_sym
    end || ALAISES.find do |k,v|
      v.include?(token.downcase.to_sym)
    end&.first
  end
end
```

And a passing spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DurationParser do
  describe '.parse' do
    it "handles hours" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 h')).to eq 1.hour;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 hr')).to eq 1.hour;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 hour')).to eq 1.hour;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('3 hours')).to eq 3.hours;
    end
    it "handles minutes" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 m')).to eq 1.minute;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 min')).to eq 1.minute;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 minute')).to eq 1.minute;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('2 minutes')).to eq 2.minutes;
    end
    it "handles seconds" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 s')).to eq 1.second;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 sec')).to eq 1.second;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 second')).to eq 1.second;
      expect(DurationParser.parse('15 seconds')).to eq 15.seconds;
    end
    it "handles comma delimeted strings" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 hour, 3 minutes, 15 seconds')).to eq(
        1.hour + 3.minutes + 15.seconds
      )
    end
    it "handles 'and' delimeted strings" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 hour and 3 minutes and 15 seconds')).to eq(
        1.hour + 3.minutes + 15.seconds
      )
    end
    it "handles mixed delimeter strings" do
      expect(DurationParser.parse('1 hour and 3 minutes, 15 seconds')).to eq(
        1.hour + 3.minutes + 15.seconds
      )
    end
    it "raises when a bad token is passed" do
      expect { DurationParser.parse('25 sols') }.to raise_error(DurationParser::ParseError) 
    end
  end
end
```

Of course if you want something reliably machine readable you want to use [ISO8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and not a wonky string parser.

Comment: Regexes are not my strong suite so this could probably be simplefied.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed ISO8601 would be great but I do not have a hand on the data